# operator does not exist: integer = integer[] postgres error in inner join question

Tags: postgresql

I tried to do this in postgres why is not append?

```
SELECT
users.countries
FROM
users
INNER JOIN countries
    ON countries.id = users.countries
ORDER BY countries;
```

Comment: What is the datatype for `countries` column in `users` table? Likely it is not matching the type of `id` column in countries table.

Comment: Don't model relationships with arrays. SQL will be complicated, performance will be bad, and you won't be able to create a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the join condition integer = array integer, it is not right. You must extract array elements after then you can use the joining condition. The best way for extracting array elements on PostgreSQL is to use `unnest` function. Also the performance of `unnest` is high. Examples:

```
-- Sample 1 
select us.*, ct.country_name   
from
    users us 
inner join 
    countries ct on ct.id in (select unnest(us.countries))
order by 
    us.countries;


-- Sample 2 
select t_us.*, ct.country_name  from 
    (
        select us.username, us.first_name, us.last_name, unnest(us.countries) as country_id 
        from users us 
    ) as t_us
inner join countries ct on ct.id = t_us.country_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ANY` operator to compare a single value with an array of values:

```
SELECT users.countries, countries.*
FROM users
  JOIN countries ON countries.id = ANY(users.countries)
ORDER BY countries;
```

---

I do not recommend modeling one-to-many (or actually many-to-many) relationships with arrays. It's better (=more efficient, more robust) to do that with a "classic" mapping table between users and countries.